# SlickGrid does dataview.deleteItem() also remove actual Grid data

Tags: slickgrid

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the interaction of Grid data with dataView but if I delete a row(s) in the dataview:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  dataViewMG2.deleteItem(i);
}
```

it seems to me that it should not remove the actual data from the dataArray object.  I should be able to again setItems() and redisplay the data:

```
dataViewMG2.beginUpdate();
dataViewMG2.setItems(modaldata2);
dataViewMG2.endUpdate();
```

Yet... when I inspect the data object (modaldata2), it has a length of 0.
Can someone explain this to me?

As always... thanks.

Comment: For whatever reason, I found a solution.  deleteItem(i) does appear to delete data from the Grid (dataObject) leaving it with length=0 but invalidateRow(i) does not.  It removes rows from the dataView but not from the dataObject (Grid).  So that redisplaying the data is as simple as updating the dataView and invalidating the grid.

Comment: Neither the question nor the "solution" comment above has enough information to be at all meaningful.

Comment: Hmm... I thought it was very clear.  I was deleting rows from the dataView using a "for" loop and deleteItem(i).  This is actually removing data from both the data array (Grid) and the datView (which I thought was decoupled from the Grid).  But when I use invalidateRow(i) it works as expected... removing rows from the dataView but not touching the data array.  Not sure how much plainer I can make it.